# TestNG : run tests sequentially

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, testng

I have a problem to configure in a correct way my testng.xml.

I want to run all my test sequentially. One by one.

in my xml file I have this code :

```
<test name="Init" preserve-order="true" parallel="false">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.Init" />
        <class name="tests.test1" />
        <class name="tests.test2" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

but when I run testng, all the three tests run at the same time.

How can I set testng to launch one test after another ?

Comment: Not sure if it's fine for your case, but you can do it with JUnit using @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING) with naming your tests this way.

Answer (score 1):

What TestNG version are you using? I'm not sure that you can declare **parallel = "false"**, it must be one of these levels: methods, classes, tests, instances. [see this](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests)

Try to change:

```
<test name="Init" preserve-order="true" parallel="false">
```

To:

```
<suite name="TestSuite" thread-count="1" parallel="classes" preserve-order="true">
```